Using VoiceOver Accessibility ,how to signal the user that a link would leave the app, for example to open the device settings in iOS App using UIKit
How to signal the user that a link would leave the app, for example to open the device settings, Appstore, email, device browser or deep link.
Voice adds "webview" to the speech when a browser is opened. It also adds "phone" when the user is about to leave the app and Phone app is opened. Is it enough to assume that this is handled automatically or should I also post a notification as below:
 UIAccessibility.post(notification: UIAccessibility.Notification.screenChanged, argument: self)

As per Accessibility Guidelines:
GIVING USERS ADVANCED WARNING WHEN OPENING A NEW WINDOW
Which means to help people understand what will happen before activating the link. I believe this shouldn't happen after the button is clicked but even before that. How can we handle it inside Outlet. Should we add descriptive localised text as accessibilityHint that this will take you outside of App(Device Settings/ Appstore) or is there a existing Apple way doing it.

I'd suggest adding an accessibility hint to the link "opens link in external browser" (or language to that effect.)

Yes I have done the same
